# Adding an overloaded constructor and two methods (Java)

Tags: java, class, constructor

So I am wanting to implement the MyPoint class, which models a 2D point with x and y coordinates.

It needs to contain the following requirements:

- Two public instance variables: x (of type int) and y (of type int).
- A toString() method that returns a string description of the instance in the format "(x, y)".
- A default (or "no-argument" or "no-arg") constructor that constructs a point at the default location of (0, 0).
- An overloaded constructor that constructs a point with the given x and y coordinates.
- An overloaded constructor that constructs a point with the given MyPoint object.
- Getter and setter for the instance variables x and y.
- A method named setXY(newx, newy) to set both x and y.
- A method named getXY() that returns the x and y in a 2-element int array.

This is the code I have written up so far:

```
class MyPoint {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public String toString(){

    }

    public MyPoint(){
        this(0, 0);
    }

    public MyPoint(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setX (int x){
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public void setY (int y){
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }

}
```

I have done all the others, but, I got stuck on writing an overloaded constructor with the given MyPoint object and implementing the getXY and setXY methods (highlighted), and overall getting the code to work.

Would the overloaded constructor with the given MyPoint object look similar to:

```
public MyPoint(int x, int y){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is this for school?

Comment: Yes, it is homework that I am trying to figure out.

Comment: The word you need to look for is a "copy constructor".
Come back and ask some more if you get stuck.

Am leaving the answer like this as it's a school homework question.

Comment: In terms of the solution, the question is pretty much self explanatory on what you must do. The point of homework is you study and figure things out even though it might not be the best solution. Try harder.

Comment: @GhostCat Noted and edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

For overloading constructor

```
public MyPoint(MyPoint p){
        this.x =p.x;
        this.y =p.y;
    }
```

for setXY() and getXY()

```
  public void setXY (int x,int y){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;

        }
          public int[] getXY ()
        { 
        return new int[]{this.x,this.y};

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The overloaded constructor with the given MyPoint object will be taking MyPoint object as argument as shown below:

```
public MyPoint(MyPoint point) {
    this.x = point.x;
    this.y = point.y;
}
```

This kind of overloaded constructor is known as **Copy Constructor**

Answer (score 0):

public MyPoint(MyPoint mp)
{

this.x = mp.x;

this.y = mp.y;

}

Note : You should pass only MyPoint type reference variable